# Comparing solid angles in arbitrary dimension

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Given two sets of unit norm real vectors $S_1$ and $S_2$ with the same shape(both of them are $d\times d$).

One can get solid angles $SA(S_1)$ and  $SA(S_2)$ out of them.

Since there are many lectures on how to compute the $SA: R^{d\times d}\to R$ and it's hard to do so.

And I'm interested in is there any easy way to compare them? Since $SA$ can be treated as a scalar function, so the comparison is well defined.

For example, is determinant $Det(S)$ approximate $SA(S)$ close enough for comparison purposes?

would $Det(S_1) > Det(S_2)$ suggest $ SA(S_1) > SA(S_2)$  ?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: thanks, sorry for the cross-posting in [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676447/solid-angles-comparison), solid angles is more of the physics math object? I'm really interested in the problem, so i thought to learn from both communities :)

Comment: "with the same shape" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: they are both $d \times d$, the shape is referring to the matrix shape